# Make Entire StackPanel Invisible If TextBlock Is Empty

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListBox of phone numbers.  Some have extensions and some do not.  I don't want the entire StackPanel to be visible if the extension is empty.  Here is what I have:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="ext "/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Extension}"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

I'm hoping to do this all in XAML.

Comment: Are you want to highlight stackpanel if ext. is blank ?

Comment: If the content of the second TextBlock is blank, I want the entire StackPanel to be invisible. IOW, I don't want the ext to show if there is no value for Extension.

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by the link ASh posted.  Got it working:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="2,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=extension, Path=Text}" 
                  Value="">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="ext "/>
    <TextBlock Name="extension" Text="{Binding Extension}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: shouldn't it rather be Style for StackPanel itself?

Comment: `<StackPanel.Resources>` -> `<StackPanel.Style>`

Comment: ASh, I'm quite a noob at this.  Could you please give me more detail?  Thanx.